# Change tabbarindex or setviewcontroller when app is start

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to change **viewControllers** in tabbar if user != nil.

I have two viewControllers which can changed:

1) **ProfileVC**

2) **SignInVC**

But when my app is start, user sees different viewController, he is **NewsVC**.

Me need to do a check before running the application and replace viewController in tabbar.

Roughly so in AppDelegate.swift:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")
        window?.rootViewController = profileVC
    } else {
        let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC")
        window?.rootViewController = loginVC
    }
}
```

But it's not correct way. How me change index or viewController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the `UITabBarController` and manage it's `viewControllers` array

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

       // if you will say force - unwrapped it's the developer job to keep track here          

        let signUp = self.viewControllers![0]

        let profile = self.viewControllers![1]

        let newsFeeds = self.viewControllers![2]

        if user == nil {

            self.viewControllers = [signUp] // leave signup only

        }

    }


}
```

assign `MainTabBarController` to the tab in IB

Comment: I little bit understand, but how it make?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set an index for the viewcontroller .

This is how you do it programatically:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let nav1 = UINavigationController()
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let profileVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC") as! //your VC
    nav1.viewControllers = [profileVC]

    let nav2 = UINavigationController()
    let loginVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC") as! //Your VC 
    nav2.viewControllers = [loginVC]

    let tabController = UITabBarController()
    tabController.viewControllers = [profileVC, loginVC]
    tabController.selectedIndex = 0 //This line will solve your question & take you to the profileVC
    self.window!.rootViewController =  tabController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```